# How can I input a depth image to let kinect output a skeleton?

Tags: kinect, openkinect

My research is to make the skeleton more stable, for now I want to try it by make the depth image better and then get a skeleton based on the processed image, but I don't know how to make it happen since Kinect only provide APIs to get the output data

Answer (score 0):

Now you are trying to do the exact opposite of what the Kinect is capable of. You can't put any pre processing depth image but you can apply some image processing on the depth image stream it retrieves.